ROS2 OrbSlam3 Mono-Inertial
Currently, I am working on OrbSlam3 in combination with ROS2. I want to run Monocular-Inertial using my own IMU and Monocular camera. Since I haven’t found any existing ROS2 OrbSlam3 Mono-Inertial packages, I tried to adapt the existing package from Mechazo11 for my use-case. He only provides the package for the use of an existing video example. But I managed to adapt the package so that I can use the Monocular configuration with my own camera in real time. Now I want to add my IMU, and therefore adapted the Code of the specific files below.
When I start the program and start moving the camera, images with some features occur. But the program crashes pretty quickly (after 3seconds focusing on the same features) and the following error messages gets printed:
Empty IMU measurements vector!!!
Not preintegrated measurement
[ros2run]: Segmentation fault
With different IMU timestamps (from the initial IMU header message) I got the following error message:
computeActiveErrors(): found NaN in error for edge 0x7a40584e0400 […]
buildSystem(): NaN within Jacobian for edge 0x7a40586070f0 for vertex 0 […]
void g2o::SparseOptimizer::update(const double*): Update contains a nan for vertex 16
I have already tried to adapt the the EuRoC.yaml file and the IMU/Images synchronization, but the error still remains.
This is the link to the package: https://github.com/Mechazo11/ros2_orb_slam3
These are the two files that I have adapted (I also updated EuRoC.yaml with the specific values of my sensors).
common cpp https://pastecode.io/s/6vg58rco
mono driver node https://pastecode.io/s/utwz9r5n
